# Error on upgrade from angular 2 to angular 4

Tags: angular

Meet problem after I upgrade my angular 2 app to angular ( 4.0)
I had replace with:

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": { 
      "dev": "environments/environment.ts", 
      "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts" 
 }
```

in my `angular-cli.json`

Here is my error.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAFPw.jpg)

How can I solve the

```
background:url('../../../../assets/img/sprite/ticket-zigzag.png') no-repeat bottom;
```

I put the image in assets folder

Comment: Please include error information as text, copy and paste it. Do not use screen shots as they can not be searched on.

Comment: Your path to image is wrong, change the path according to your project's folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the relative path of the image. Make sure that this path is relative to one of the following (depending on the type of loader you are using in webpack)

1. The html file your are using the image path in
2. The bundled file in your build destination